# How to use multiple whereHas with where in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using where with multiple whereHas() and i'm not getting the expected result.

This is my code

```php
public function getCommunityScoreByUser($user,$category_id) {
      $question_ids = $user->answers->pluck('question_id')->unique();

      $specialities = $this->speciality
                    ->whereHas('questions', function($qry) use($question_ids){
                        $qry->whereIn('questions.id', $question_ids);
                       })
                    ->orwhereHas('caseStudies', function($qry) use($user) {
                        $qry->where('user_id', $user->id);
                       })
                    ->where('is_active', 'Y')
                    ->where('category_id',$category_id)
                    ->withCount('answers')
                    ->withCount(['answers as bestAnswerCount' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('question_answer.is_accepted','Y');
                                }])
                    ->with(['answers' => function ($query) {
                          $query->withCount(['votes' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('count','1');
                             }]);
                      }])
                    ->get();
      foreach ($specialities as $speciality => $key) {
        $votes_count = 0;
        foreach ($key->answers as $key1 => $value) {
          $votes_count += $value->votes_count;
        }
        $key->votesCount = $votes_count;
        $key->totalVotes = (3*$key->bestAnswerCount)+$votes_count+$key->case_study_votes_count;
      }
      return $specialities;
}
```

**Expected result**

I want to fetch specialities which have either questions, or case-studies and it should meet the criteria `->where('category_id',$category_id)`

**Actual result**

`$specialities` conatins either questions, or case-studies, But it's not checking the `category_id`. Instead, it fetches `$specialities` with all the categories. But if i remove one of the whereHas, then it's working perfectly.

Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you get is due to the `orWhereHas`. With your current statement, it will get all specialities where it has questions OR where it has case studies where is active etc etc.

What you want to do is limit the `or` to just the `whereHas` statements.

To do this you can do the following :

```
$specialities = $this->speciality
    ->where(function ($qry) use ($question_ids, $user) {
        $qry->whereHas('questions', function ($qry) use ($question_ids) {
            $qry->whereIn('questions.id', $question_ids);
        })->orwhereHas('caseStudies', function ($qry) use ($user) {
            $qry->where('user_id', $user->id);
        });
    })
    ->where('is_active', 'Y')
    ->where('category_id', $category_id)
    ->withCount('answers')
    ->withCount(['answers as bestAnswerCount' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('question_answer.is_accepted', 'Y');
    }])
    ->with(['answers' => function ($query) {
        $query->withCount(['votes' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('count', '1');
        }]);
    }])
    ->get();
```

What this will do is just wrap the `whereHas`'s in their own where so they are treated independently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's just that the enclosing where doesn't use parameters to work on it's child whereHas

Comment: @Nadiya Yea that was my bad, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `orWhereHas` is probably not behaving the way you expect it to. In your case if

```
->orwhereHas('caseStudies', function($qry) use($user) {
     $qry->where('user_id', $user->id);
})
```

is true, then it will be allowed. It will not need to check all other filters.

If you want to check one or the other `whereHas` you will need to add these into their own `where` to kind of 'limit' the `or`.

```
->where(function($query) use ($question_ids, $user){
    $query->whereHas('questions', function($qry) use($question_ids){
        $qry->whereIn('questions.id', $question_ids);
    })
    ->orwhereHas('caseStudies', function($qry) use($user) {
        $qry->where('user_id', $user->id);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked by have a typo in ->where(function($query) use ($uqestion_ids, $user){